# How to truncate/empty huge SQL log files

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2019

I've got some databases that are around 500mb with log files that are 50+gb.

reading through I've seen transaction log backups weren't done so i suspect that's the reason for this growth over the years. I'm setting up Always on replication and would like to empty out the transaction log files prior to the always-on setup.

I've followed some answers like:
https://theitbros.com/truncate-sql-server-2012-transaction-logs/
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-transaction-log-backup-truncate-and-shrink-operations/

But i'm not able to shrink the files to any moderate size. Is there a way to empty out the log files and bring them down back to +- 100mb?

I've set the DB's to simple recovery model, ran the TSQL below but it's still not releasing. When opening the reports i see that there is no empty space to release even after setting to simple recovery mode. I'm okay with loosing point-in-time restore as, once the logs have been resized i will flip everything back to full and take a full backup.

```
USE [AdventureWorks2016CTP3]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'AdventureWorks2016CTP3_Log' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
```

I've already taken full backups prior to doing anything just for safety.
Any tips/guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `TRUNCATEONLY`.

```
USE [AdventureWorks2016CTP3]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'AdventureWorks2016CTP3_Log' , 100)
GO
```

Comment: Hi Wouter, coming back to you on this i see now that it worked for some not for others, IE certain log files don't drop down to 100mb, rather jsut a small amount?

Comment: I have a log file that is 4,211,392KB once i run the transaction it doesn't change, same size

Comment: Make sure you generate some transactions (do an update but roll back for example).  Then try again.